# How can I search a file for a specific string until a blank line and paste that into the first line of a different file?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I have tried
 `sed -n '/- name: string/,/^$/p' dire1/main.yml >> dire2/README.md`

This does not add anything, I also want it to add it to the first line of dire2/readme.md if readme.md does not already include '- name: string' in the first line so as not to get duplicates.

For example if a file includes

```
- name: first step 
  uses: message

- name: second step
```

I'd want

```
- name: first step 
  uses: message
```

to be included in the first line of readme.md. But if readme.md already has this in the first line, it should not be added.

Another example
The file is a longer file

```
name: build
another line here
yet another line

- name: title here
   another line 
   another line

- name: another title
   more lines here
   more lines 
 
- name: third title
  more lines
  more lines
```

In this example, i'd want it to populate the readme.md file with

```
- name: title here
   another line 
   another line
```

or any one of the other paragraphs beginning with '- name ' and ending at a blank line.

This all has to be searched from one file and added to the beginning of readme file if it doesn't already exist

Thank you for any help

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks. Also, by _a black line_ I assume you meant a blank line?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have made the changes

Answer (score 0):

I build a quick awk solution, works for your example.
First, the 3 example files:

```
kent$  head *.yml                                                                        
==> main.yml <==
- name: first step 
  uses: message

- name: second step

==> readme1.yml <==
key: 
  whatever2: 200

==> readme2.yml <==
- name: exists
  users: whatever

- key: 
  whatever2: 100
```

As you can see, the `readme1.yml` doesn't contain the first key (`- name: xxx`) in the main.yml. While the `readme2.yml` contains the key already.

Now the awk command: (the two commands are the same, only the input params are different):

```
$ awk -F':' -v RS="" 'NR==FNR{if(NR==1){k=$1;a[k]=$0;}next;} FNR==1 && !($1 in a){print a[k]}1' main.yml readme1.yml
- name: first step 
  uses: message
key: 
  whatever2: 200

$ awk -F':' -v RS="" 'NR==FNR{if(NR==1){k=$1;a[k]=$0;}next;} FNR==1 && !($1 in a){print a[k]}1' main.yml readme2.yml
- name: exists
  users: whatever
- key: 
  whatever2: 100
```

So, if you check the outputs above, it seems they are what you expected.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have tried it and I am not getting that same result for some reason. I may need to tweak it but it would be ok for you to explain the awk command you have used?

Comment: @user16007126 which part you don't get?

Comment: I may not have been clear in my original question but your solution only takes the first line with 'name' at the beginning without the -. I need it to be specific in which string it wants to take. 
the '-name' could be in several places in the file

Comment: @user16007126 it's always good to provide an example to cover all cases of your real problem, unless you've known how to handle the cases not covered by the example. If it's not easy to be extracted as one single example, add more examples with descriptions please.

Comment: Of course, I am still learning. I have edited the original question, I hope that is better

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed you can extract the blocks and quit after the first:

```
sed -n '/^- name.*$/,/^$/{p;/^$/q}' file
- name: title here
    another line 
    another line
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. this is one part of it, it has to be added to the beginning of another file if it doesn't already exist there